# Not able to call Custom Apex Rest API from Visual-force page in java-script (POST redirect to GET)

Tags: visualforce, lightning, apexrest

I have a requirement where I need to call my custom written Apex REST api from java-script in visualforce page, But somehow I'm getting that CORS issue which says my request has been blocked due to following error:

> No `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header is present on the requested
>   resource

I know now it shouldn't throw any kind of CORS issue, because as per summer 16 release CORS is supported by Apex REST service, refer below post:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_apex_rest_cors.htm

And I already added request origin url (which is VF) in the CORS settings, `Setup >> CORS`

Second weird thing is it always show me GET call in the dev console, although I'm making a POST call in the API, may be it because of any redirection behavior. Please find error screenshot from my dev console.
[image]

Can anyone suggests what's gone wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS in Salesforce is all kinds of messed up...  The standard REST API (`services/data`) works fine in most cases (you actually don't even need CORS).

However, when send a request to `https://yourdomain.visualforce.com/services/apexrest/*`, salesforce will `301` redirect you to `https://yourdomain.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/*`.

Unfortunately when it does this, it doesn't seem to preserve the http method (`POST` in this case) and always redirects to `GET`.

You can solve this by instead just sending your requests directly to `https://yourdomain.salesforce.com/` in the first place.  You will of course, need a CORS whitelist for `https://yourdomain.visualforce.com`.

*TIP*: You can get the standard URL of your ORG in visualforce like this:

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">    
      const restHost = '{!URLFOR("/", null)}';
      const accessToken = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks! it will help someone else here.